# I'm very new to javascript, Can you please write a code to close the menu button in the mobile section

Tags: mobile, responsive-design

The below code is working for me but I facing one problem here, in a responsive mobile view, when I clicked on the client menu it is opening but I'm unable to close the clients. Can you please guys help me in this situation.The below code is working for me but I facing one problem here, in a responsive mobile view, when I clicked on the client menu it is opening but I'm unable to close the clients. Can you please guys help me in this situation.
The below code is working for me but I facing one problem here, in a responsive mobile view, when I clicked on the client menu it is opening but I'm unable to close the clients. Can you please guys help me in this situation.

````
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
body {margin:0;font-family:Arial}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 17px;    
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.topnav a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child), .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown {float: none;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">clients 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div> 
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
</div>


<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>```
````

Comment: can you guys write a script to close the client's menu bar in mobile responsive

Answer (score 0):

Not clearly understand your question. Anyway, I think your problem is about media queries. Use this for mobile versions. I hope this works.

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px) {
.YourClass {---}
```

}

Comment: can you please create a sample page and paste the code and save as HTML page. When you open the page in chrome, inspect it. in the mobile view around 500px, we can observe mobile menu right. When we click on the toggle it will show the menu items, In the menu items, we have clients menu. When we click on clients, a submenu is opening but I'm unable to close the clients submenu. I want to close the submenu when user double click on it. Can you please make it

Comment: can you please create a sample page and paste the code and save as HTML page. When you open the page in chrome, inspect it. in the mobile view around 500px, we can observe mobile menu right. When we click on the toggle it will show the menu items, In the menu items, we have clients menu. When we click on clients, a submenu is opening but I'm unable to close the clients submenu. I want to close the submenu when user double click on it. Can you please make it